# How to query a parse-server object with a filter based on date in swift 4?

Tags: swift, database, date

I have seen many old answers online with regards on how to filter query an object based on date, but they all seem to cause errors based on the old-ness of the code. Here is what I would like to do:
The user (via a `UISlider` and a button) sets max time (in days) away from today they'd like to filter the objects from, stored as a float due to ~reasons~.

```
let maxDateFilter: Float = 6
```

I would then like them to filter the query based on this constraint, roughly, as follows:

```
let futureMaxDate = Date() + maxDateFilter //obviously this is wrong
query.whereKey("date", greaterThanOrEqualTo: Date())//today
query.whereKey("date", lessThanOrEqualTo: futureMaxDate
```

Obviously the syntax in `futureMaxDate` is wrong, but how do I go about setting up this declaration? I don't care about the time, I just need the day to be within, in this case, 6 calendar days. I think I need to use an `NSCalendar`, but, again, the answers online appear outdated.